# Confluent Kafka SMT: Timestamp conversion issue

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am completely new to Kafka and have been trying to get a few basic use cases work.

What I'm trying to accomplish? Load data into a Kafka topic from a table in Oracle. (Using query based CDC)

Goal: Get the date format correct when I read data from the topic.

The data for date column is coming thru as epoch. I included timestamp transform step in the connector config to convert it to dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss format and have not been able to get it to work.

Below is what I have in the connector config. I tried a few combinations of the format, changed the target type as string but I still see epoch values.

```
            "incrementing.column.name": "MD_LOAD_NUMBER",
            "validate.non.null": "false",
            "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
            "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
            "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
            "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
            "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",

            "transforms":"insrt_dt, updt_dt",
            "transforms.insrt_dt.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
            "transforms.insrt_dt.target.type": "Timestamp",
            "transforms.insrt_dt.field": "MD_INSERT_DATE",
            "transforms.insrt_dt.format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
            "transforms.updt_dt.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
            "transforms.updt_dt.target.type": "Timestamp",
            "transforms.updt_dt.field": "MD_UPDATE_DATE",
            "transforms.updt_dt.format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

ksql> print biORGANIZATION_DIM from beginning;

Key format: SESSION(AVRO) or HOPPING(AVRO) or TUMBLING(AVRO) or AVRO or SESSION(PROTOBUF) or HOPPING(PROTOBUF) or TUMBLING(PROTOBUF) or PROTOBUF or SESSION(JSON) or HOPPING(JSON) or TUMBLING(JSON) or JSON or SESSION(JSON_SR) or HOPPING(JSON_SR) or TUMBLING(JSON_SR) or JSON_SR or SESSION(KAFKA_INT) or HOPPING(KAFKA_INT) or TUMBLING(KAFKA_INT) or KAFKA_INT or SESSION(KAFKA_BIGINT) or HOPPING(KAFKA_BIGINT) or TUMBLING(KAFKA_BIGINT) or KAFKA_BIGINT or SESSION(KAFKA_DOUBLE) or HOPPING(KAFKA_DOUBLE) or TUMBLING(KAFKA_DOUBLE) or KAFKA_DOUBLE or SESSION(KAFKA_STRING) or HOPPING(KAFKA_STRING) or TUMBLING(KAFKA_STRING) or KAFKA_STRING

Value format: AVRO

rowtime: 6/4/20 10:49:19 AM PDT, key: , value: {"ORGANIZATION_KEY": -1, "ORGANIZATION_ID": null, "ORGANIZATION_NAME": "UNASSIGNED", "SET_OF_BOOKS_ID": null, "MD_INSERT_DATE": 1404321287000, "MD_UPDATE_DATE": 1404321287000, "MD_DELETED_FLAG": "N"}

I referred to https://www.confluent.de/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector/ and https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/timestampconverter.html

How do I convert the date into easily readable format? 
Any help is appreciated and thank you for reading thru a long post!

Version: confluent local version
    The local commands are intended for a single-node development environment
    only, NOT for production usage. https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

Confluent Community Software: 5.5.0

Answer (score 1):

Change to transforms.insrt_dt.target.type :"string".It should work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Debezium Documentation](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/oracle.html#oracle-temporal-types) you can add the property:

```
"time.precision.mode":"connect"
```

It will make the **oracle date types be treated as Kafka Connect built-in date types**.

I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64346860/how-to-format-timestamp-value-to-date-format-in-confluent-kafka-connect-jdbc-o/66856194#66856194) before here that seems similar to this one for MySQL source connector.